# OpenGL ShadowMap set correct matrices

Tags: c++, opengl, shadow-mapping

I use vector as light position say (0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f) and an object positioned at (0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f) and a plane.

```
lightSpaceProjection = glm::ortho(-10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f, 1.0f, 300.0f);
lightSpaceView= glm::lookAt(lightPosition, glm::vec3(0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
lightSpaceMatrix = lightSpaceProjection * lightSpaceView;
```

I get a shadow moving with the camera everywhere, I want to know how to update the shadow map to render the right space shadow where the camera looks at.

I calculate the light space matrix as shown to send it to the vertex shader to render the shadow map from the light view, then send it again to the normal vertex shader to calculate which fragment is in shadow,

the light definition

```
DirectLight sun;
sun.direction = glm::vec3(0.0f, 10.0f, 5.0f);
sun.lightSpaceProjection = glm::ortho(-10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f, 1.0f, 300.0f);
sun.lightSpaceView= glm::lookAt(sun.direction, glm::vec3(0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
scene.addLight("sun", sun);
```

this is the render code

```
    DirectLight& sun = dynamic_cast<DirectLight&>(this->getLight("sun", LIGHTTYPE_DIRECT));
    glm::mat4 lightSpaceMatrix = (sun.lightSpaceProjection * sun.lightSpaceView);
    glViewport(0, 0, SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthMapFBO);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //glCullFace(GL_FRONT);

    typedef std::map<std::string, Model>::iterator model_it;
    depthShader.use();
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(depthShader.getProgramID(), "lightSpaceMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(lightSpaceMatrix));
    for (model_it it = phongModels.begin(); it != phongModels.end(); it++) {
        ((Model&) it->second).drawDepth(depthShader);
    }
    //glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    // draw normal
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    typedef std::map<std::string, Model>::iterator model_it;
    phongShader.use();
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(phongShader.getProgramID(), "lightSpaceMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(lightSpaceMatrix));
    this->drawPhongLights(phongShader);
    this->setViewUniforms(phongShader);
    for (model_it it = phongModels.begin(); it != phongModels.end(); it++) {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(phongShader.getProgramID(), "shadowMap"), 2);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap);
        ((Model&) it->second).drawPhong(phongShader, this->defCamera);
    }
```

the depth vertex shader is

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
uniform mat4 lightSpaceMatrix;
uniform mat4 model;

void main(){
    gl_Position = lightSpaceMatrix * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);
}
```

and the normal vertex shader is

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;

out vec2 TexCoords;
out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 LightPos;
out vec4 FragPosLightSpace;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform mat4 lightSpaceMatrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);     
    TexCoords = vec2(texCoord.s,1.0-texCoord.t);
    Normal=normal;
    FragPos = vec3(view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f));
    LightPos = vec3(view * vec4(lightPos, 1.0));
    FragPosLightSpace = lightSpaceMatrix * vec4(FragPos, 1.0);
}
```

and in fragment shader i calculate the shadow by this function

```
float directShadowCalculation(vec4 fragPosLightSpace,float bias){
    vec3 projCoords = fragPosLightSpace.xyz / fragPosLightSpace.w;
    projCoords = projCoords * 0.5 + 0.5;
    float closestDepth = vec3(texture(shadowMap, projCoords.xy)).r;
    float currentDepth = projCoords.z;
    float shadow = 0.0;
    vec2 texelSize = 1.0 / textureSize(shadowMap, 0);
    for(int x = -1; x <= 1; ++x){
        for(int y = -1; y <= 1; ++y){
            float pcfDepth = texture(shadowMap, projCoords.xy + vec2(x, y) * texelSize).r; 
            shadow += currentDepth - bias > pcfDepth  ? 1.0 : 0.0;        
        }    
    }
    shadow /= 9.0;
    if(projCoords.z > 1.0)
        shadow = 0.0;    
    return shadow;
    }
```

then apply the color by this one

```
vec3 calcDirectLight(DirectLight light){
    vec3 color = vec3(texture(mat_diffuse, TexCoords));

    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize( light.direction  - FragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff ;

    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);

    float spec =0.0;
    if(blinn){
        vec3 halfwayDir = normalize(lightDir + viewDir);
        spec = pow(max(dot(norm, halfwayDir), 0.0), 16.0);
    }
    else{
        vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);
        spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), 8.0);
    }

    //float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), shininess);
    vec3 specular = spec * light.specular;
    float bias = max(0.05 * (1.0 - dot(norm, lightDir)), 0.005);
    float shadow = directShadowCalculation(FragPosLightSpace,bias);     
    vec3 result =light.intensity* (light.ambient+ ((1.0 - shadow) * (diffuse + specular)))*color;
    return result;
}
```

i don't know how to update the light space frustum with camera view

Solution:
the bug was in the vertex shader, this is the correct one:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;

out vec2 TexCoords;
out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 FragPos;
out vec4 FragPosLightSpace;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform mat4 lightSpaceMatrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);     
    TexCoords = vec2(texCoord.s,1.0-texCoord.t);
    Normal=transpose(inverse(mat3(model))) * normal;;
    FragPos = vec3( model * vec4(position, 1.0f));
    FragPosLightSpace = lightSpaceMatrix * vec4(FragPos, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: In which space (world, view, NDC) is the position of the light? How do you use the light? Please, provide a minimal code.

Comment: Digging in that dense code I see two suspiciously similar shader in-out vars: `fragPosLightSpace` and `FragPosLightSpace` Letter case matters.

Comment: Sorry gentlemen, i found the bug it was in the vertex shader, i was multiply the FragPos uniform by the view matrix, the correct is in edit